# Branch.io - Android app links DAL json file not updated when SHA256 changed

Tags: branch.io

We are using Branch.io for app links in our application. We have 4 different versions of application for different environments. All versions were working properly with generated app links, but now we need to updated SHA256 fingerpints for our production app as it was published on Play Store using Google's signing keys.

The issue is that after updating SHA256 fingerpints in Branch dashboard content of Digital Asset Links JSON file "/.well-known/assetlinks.json" is not updated even after few days.

What I have tried so far:
- replaced previous SHA256 with a new one
- added new SHA256, as we won't to have 2 SHA256 fingerpints provided in DAL file
- disabled app links for Android just to try triggering DAL file re-generation

Here is example content of DAL json file:

```
[
  {
    "relation":["delegate_permission/common.handle_all_urls"],
    "target":{
      "namespace":"android_app",
      "package_name":"<my app package name>",
      "sha256_cert_fingerprints":[
         "<my app existing sha256 fingerpint>"
      ]
    }
  }
]
```

And I need to have it's "sha256_cert_fingerprints" field updated with new sha256 fingerprint:

```
[
  {
    "relation":["delegate_permission/common.handle_all_urls"],
    "target":{
      "namespace":"android_app",
      "package_name":"<my app package name>",
      "sha256_cert_fingerprints":[
         "<my app sha256 fingerprint for Play Store APK>"
         "<my app existing sha256 fingerpint>"
      ]
    }
  }
]
```

Branch declares that they support multiple SHA256 fingerprints:
"You can insert both your debug and production fingerprints for testing. Simply separate them with a comma"
https://docs.branch.io/deep-linking/android-app-links/

None of my attempts helped and "assetlinks.json" DAL file stays unchanged. Does anyone know how to force Branch to generate DAL json file again, so it will include updated SHA256 fingerprints in it?

Answer (score 2):

We ran into the same as you (lost hours on it). You just need to invalidate the contents on the Branch console for your app, save it and update it with actual contents that you need, it should force Branch to update your appLinks.json DAL file (if you are not self-hosting it).

[image]